# Whatever happened to Jonathan O'Neill?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the SG-1 episode "Fragile Balance" (S7:E03), a [15-year-old boy](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_O%27Neill) shows up at SGC claiming to be Jack O'Neill. The team determines that Jack was abducted and somehow reverted to a younger age. Later in the episode, they figure out that

> the teenager is actually a clone of Jack, one who did not mature properly due to the technique used to create him. The clone takes the name "Jonathan" (as "Jack" is O'Neill's middle name) and decides to go back to high school, having a second chance to embrace the childhood he never had the first time around.

**Has any Stargate-related material mentioned what happens to Jonathan after this episode?**

I looked on the [Stargate wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_O'Neill) but it only mentions the events of the episode. Then again, the wiki is primarily focused on the TV show and typically doesn't mention novels or comics. Given young Jonathan's knowledge & experience, one would think he'd be an ideal candidate for the Stargate or Atlantis programs in a few years' time.

Comment: I watched this episode (for the second time) last night.  Good episode!

Comment: Jack is not O'Neill's middle name; it is a diminuitive of Jonathan. As such, that entire quote is suspect, and I don't remember anything in the show about the clone specifically going by their full first name.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you could be right, I dunno. His full name is Jonathan J. O'Neill and when the clone decides to go by "Jonathan", Jack says something like he never liked that name. As for the clone's name, I added a wiki link.

Comment: _"when the clone decides to go by 'Jonathan', Jack says something like he never liked that name"_ I don't remember anything like that. Was there perhaps a deleted or extended scene? Or is it from a book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the main TV and film canon, the answer is a simple dunno. Jonathan O'Neill doesn't appear in (nor is he mentioned in) any of the further episodes.

---

As far as the 'additional materials' are concerned, the sole reference to him apears to be a brief mention in the SG-1 novel "[Roswell](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Roswell)":

> And yet it would also result in the loss of young Jonathan O'Neill
>   who, Teal'c understood, was—in 2006—doing well in high school and
>   preparing to enter college. Mindful of Colonel's Carter's warning that
>   altering the past could impose a greater evil on the future, Teal'c
>   said, “Loki is unable to draw breath.”

Answer (score 2):

In the Stargate Far Horizons Anthology published by Fandemonium books there is a short book titled *Off Balance*, written by Sally Malcolm that continues the story of the young clone of Jack. She continued that same story about him with a ebook novella titled *Behind Enemy Lines*, also available from Fandemonium books.

Comment: And what happened to him?